# Objective C "unable to open database file" while inserting large amount of data in loop SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, for-loop, sql-insert

I'm inserting over 42000 data within for loop and it's working fine for a while like it's inserting 2000+ data but after that crashing with the error **unable to open database file**

This is the insertion code

[image: This is the insertion code]

And this is the connection code

[image: this is the connection code]

the `insertReceiptReport` is being called in a loop. I'm new to iOS, that's why not sure what I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use synchronous thread and perform operation one by one

Comment: Use Insert multiple row with single insert statement and insert your data in single commit.

Comment: Do not post code as images. Please [edit] your question by copying and pasting the relevant code as text into your question. Images can't be searched or referenced and they are very hard to read.

Comment: @CodeChanger how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code for Inserting multiple row in single Transaction

```
char* error;
sqlite3_exec(mDb, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &error);
char buffer[] = "INSERT INTO example VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7)";
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(mDb, buffer, strlen(buffer), &stmt, NULL);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < mVal; i++) {
    std::string id = getID();
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, id.c_str(), id.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 2, getDouble());
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 3, getDouble());
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 4, getDouble());
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 5, getInt());
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 6, getInt());
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 7, getInt());
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        printf("Commit Failed!\n");
    }
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
}
sqlite3_exec(mDb, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &error);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

By This `BEGIN` & `COMMIT` Transaction you can insert multiple row in DB.

For more detail you can refer this link : [Bulk Row Insert](http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/)

**Edit:**

For  check if Data already there will update row requirement you can use below Insert query :

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO <TableName> VALUES ()
```

> Note : Above query only works if you have PRIMARY KEY in your table.

Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. for me, I'm doing like **check if data already in db** if available then `update` or if not then `insert`. in this case, is it suitable to do like you mentioned?